# Migration from Jekyll to Pelican

Tags: migration, jekyll, pelican

Pelican articles start like this:

```
Title: Training your first Neural Network
Category: My bits and bytes
Date: 2015-12-03 07:30
Tags: Science, Papers, Reading, Google Scholar
Authors: Martin Thoma

The following article gives you the necessary knowledge ...
```

Jekyll articles start like this:

```
---
layout: post
title: Training your first Neural Network
author: Martin Thoma
date: 2015-12-03 07:30
categories:
- My bits and bytes
tags:
- Science
- Papers
- Reading
- Google Scholar
featured_image: logos/science.png
---
The following article gives you the necessary knowledge ...
```

I would like to migrate my blog from Jekyll to Pelican. However, I like the Jekyll way to annotate metadata better. It is also supported by the Markdown preview on GitHub ([example](https://github.com/MartinThoma/MartinThoma.github.io/blob/source/_posts/2015-12-03-find-papers.md)) in contrast to the Pelican header type ([example](https://github.com/ML-KA/ML-KA.github.io/blob/source/content/paper-discussion-group.md)).

Is it possible to make Pelican understand the Jekyll tag list format? If not, how do I migrate Jekyll metadata to Pelican?

### Differences

- List format:

  - Pelican does not understand the tags format of Jekyll
  - Categories: I'm not sure if Pelican supports articles being in multiple categories. I'm also not sure if I have that, but again: Pelican doesn't understand the list format.
- I have no idea how Pelican handles the `featured_image`. I guess one can access this from templates?
- Is there something similar like `layout` in Pelican?
- Differences which don't matter

  - The capital first letter seems not to matter. Pelican seems to understand it, when it is lowercase.
  - The `---` before and after the metadata seems not to matter.
- Pelian has `{filename}` for [Linking to static files](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#linking-to-static-files). I guess I can write a script which searches for `../images` and replaces it with `{filename}/images`. Is it possible to tell Jekyll that `{filename}` should be replaced with `..`? This would be nice for a transition phase where I still use Jekyll, but make the code acceptable for Pelican.

Except for plugins and themes where no general answer can be given, I'm not aware of any other important differences

Comment: The Jekyll metadata section is in YAML, and there are well known parsers for that, so you can probably write the migration script yourself. Pelican does not support [multiple categories](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/349).

Comment: Use tags instead categories, that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This is the [best article I've found so far](http://www.emrealadag.com/wordpress-to-jekyll-to-pelican.html).

> First of all, I had to remove triple dashes covering the metadata:
>
> sed -i '' '/---/d' *.md
>
> Then I had to rename "categories:" to "category:"
>
> sed -i '' 's/categories:/category:/g' *.md
>
> Then I had to remove .html
>   extensions from the permalinks:
>
> sed -i '' '/permalink:/s/.html//g' *.md
>
> Then I had to rename
>   "permalink:" to "Slug:"
>
> sed -i '' '/permalink:/s/permalink:/Slug:/g' *.md
>
> Then I had to remove
>   the preceding slash from the slug:
>
> sed -i '' 's/Slug: //Slug: /g' *.md
>
> Then I had to replace some
>   characters like quotes, triple dots, dashes:
>
> sed -i '' 's/’/''/g' *.md 
>   sed -i '' 's/“/"/g' *.md 
>   sed -i '' 's/”/"/g' *.md 
>   sed -i '' 's/…/.../g' *.md 
>   sed -i '' 's/–/-/g' *.md

There's also a link to a python script for categories and tags.